# Adding n columns to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm making a program where I need to make a matrix looking like this:

```
A = np.array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
   [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
   [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
   [ 1.,  2.,  3.]])
```

So I started thinking about this `np.arange(1,4)`

But, how to append `n columns` of `np.arange(1,4)` to `A`?

Comment: Please include the *complete* code you've tried with `np.arange`

Comment: Do you want to append rows to `A` or create `A` that looks like the one in your question? For the latter case use `numpy.repeat` on axis=0.

Comment: Looks like he would like (4, 4, 4, 4) (5, 5, 5, 5), ... columns added to the array, but it's a bit vague...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get something like what you typed in your question with:

```
N = 3
A = np.tile(np.arange(1, N+1), (N, 1))
```

I'm assuming you want a square array?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html) you can use [concatenate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate)

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> b = np.array([[5, 6]])
>>> np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
>>> np.concatenate((a, b.T), axis=1)
array([[1, 2, 5],
       [3, 4, 6]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way, using broadcasting:

```
In [69]: np.arange(1,4)*np.ones((4,1))
Out[69]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> np.repeat([np.arange(1, 4)], 4, 0)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```